# Stacking Text Arguments

Tags: stacking-symbols

I was wondering was is the best method in (general) I guess to stack text on top of text in very small areas as in this example:

[image]

I used the `\stackrel` (which I think is for math more so) command but with this LaTeX makes some pre-determined assumptions and makes the top argument smaller than the bottom as seen above. I wanted all the text to be the same size. I tried several ways, but only to come up with this way which works, but is *not* optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\[
\left.\begin{aligned}
  f(\theta) & = \cos(2\theta)\\
  g(\theta) & = \sin(\theta)
\end{aligned}\right\rbrace
\begin{tabular}{l}
  Are continuous\\
  everywhere
\end{tabular}
\]
```

One might write `\begin{tabular}{@{}l}` to avoid the small space at the left of the tabular. A bit of visual formatting is always necessary: the final effect depends on many factors (for instance, the font size used).

Using `\parbox` or `minipage` here has a serious drawback: it uses up all the dedicated space, thus spoiling the global formula centering.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know you can do a right brace delimiter as so by `\rbrace`, interesting. You always have some nifty commands to present in your answers. I like that. Also, did not know about `aligned` environment. Is that anything different from `\begin{align}...\end{align}`?

Comment: @nightowl The difference is not in syntax inside the environment; but `align` (and `align*`) create an object as wide as the text width, while `aligned` occupies only the needed horizontal space.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a `\parbox`. The `rcases` environment is provided by `mathtools`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{rcases}
f(\theta) = \cos(2\theta) \\
g(\theta) = \sin(\theta)
\end{rcases}
\parbox{7em}{\small Are continous \\ everywhere}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternative to a `\parbox` with explicit width, you may use a `tabular`: `\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Are continous\\everywhere\end{tabular}`. One more Alternative may by using package [varwidth](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth).

Comment: Torbjorn: Very nice. I did not know about `parbox`. How useful is that command because it may actually make alot of things I try to accomplish much easier. And if you could, can you provide just some brief detail on what's its use in LaTeX. Thank Again.

Comment: @nightowl It simply creates a box of the specified width (here `7em`) in which you can put text. You can read more about it in [`lshort`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort) or [this document](http://ctan.org/pkg/latex2e-help-texinfo). Both of these are part of MikTeX and TeXlive, and available via `texdoc`: In a terminal or command line (or the search field in the start menu of Windows 7) write `texdoc lshort` for the first, and `texdoc latex2e` for the second. (This works in TeXLive, at least.)

Comment: Thanks! That helps alot. And the commands worked on command line, but the document was in a non-english language. hehe. So it couldn't help me much.

Comment: @nightowl Oh. Well, you can find the English versions on CTAN (the two links I posted).

Answer (score 3):

You can juse use two `aligned` environments and a brace. Adding some modification to the line spacing you can get the lines closely packed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[\left.
  \begin{aligned}
      f(\theta) & = \cos(2\theta)\\[.5\baselineskip]
      g(\theta) & = \sin(\theta)
  \end{aligned}
  \right \}
  \begin{aligned}
      &\text{are continuous}\\[-.3\baselineskip]
      &\text{everywhere}
  \end{aligned}
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image: tightly packed text after brace]

**Edit:** You can of course repace the second `aligned` with a parbox of sufficient width. That's probably better, actually. It would then become:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[\left.
  \begin{aligned}
      f(\theta) & = \cos(2\theta)\\[.5\baselineskip]
      g(\theta) & = \sin(\theta)
  \end{aligned}
  \right \}
  \parbox{3cm}{
      Are continuous\\[-.3\baselineskip]
      everywhere
  }
  \]
\end{document}
```

With the same result.

Comment: Thanks.A bit more of a dragged out way of doing things, but it makes sense systematically going through the process of what you want to accomplish. I think I might be starting to like this `parbox` command, kind of seeing what it can do comparing the difference in the two versions. `:)`.

Comment: Here a `\parbox` is surely worse than `aligned`, unless you guess exactly the required width.

Comment: @egreg: Unless you want to put something else behind it, what's the problem with using a greater width than required? EDIT: nevermind, the centering will of course be off.